# Django ORM query for last 7 days day by day

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

This is my model:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am trying to get last 7 days data like i want to see how many sales occurred in last Friday, Saturday, Monday, etc date.

Only for the last 7 days but it should appear day by day,

like:

```
friday: 40
mondey:80
widnesday: 88 etc date
```

I am not getting how to do this...

I have tried like this below:

```
some_day_last_week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)    
sales = Sales.objects.filter(
            created_at__gte=some_day_last_week,
        ).values(
            'created_at__date'
        ).annotate(
            created_count=Count('created_at__date')
        )
```

Can anyone help me with this case?

Comment: What are you getting when you print `sales_by_day`?

Comment: I am getting data date by date

Comment: But i want date in a list of dict like if friday: 80, monddy: 90 etc

Comment: @wow Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TruncDay in your case:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDay

sales = Sales.objects.filter(
            created_at__gte=some_day_last_week,
        ).annotate(
            day=TruncDay('created_at')
            created_count=Count('created_at__date')
        ).values(
            'day',
            'created_count',
        )
```

As a result you will get:

```
[
    {'day': datetime.date(2019, 12, 1), 'created_count': 4.0}, 
    {'day': datetime.date(2019, 12, 2), 'created_count': 10.0},
    {'day': datetime.date(2019, 12, 3), 'created_count': 5.0},
    {'day': datetime.date(2019, 12, 4), 'created_count': 1.0},
    {'day': datetime.date(2019, 12, 5), 'created_count': 8.0},
    {'day': datetime.date(2019, 12, 6), 'created_count': 4.0},
]
```

In order to get a date name you can convert datetime object with `date.strftime("%A")`:

```
for i in result:
    print(i['day'].strftime("%A"))

# result 
Sunday
Monday
...
Friday
```